# Why does the Fibonacci Series using Iterator and Range throw error

Tags: c++, c++11, logic, c++17

I am practicing C++ code snippets in the CPP Crash Course Book (Chapter-8, Exercise 1), [Link](http://%20https://www.amazon.in/C-Crash-Course-Josh-Lospinoso-ebook/dp/B077WZSHJV) the below does not compile and the error of the program has been provided below. It would be helpful if any suggestions or links for understanding is provided. :).

```
#include <cstdio>
struct FibonacciIterator {
    bool operator!=(int x) const {
    return x >= current; 
    }
    FibonacciIterator& operator++() {
    const auto tmp = current; 
    current += last; 
    last = tmp; 
    return *this;
    }
    int operator*() const {
    return current;
    }
private:
    int current{ 1 }, last{ 1 };
};

struct FibonacciRange {
    explicit FibonacciRange(int max) : max{ max } { }
    FibonacciIterator begin() const { 
    return FibonacciIterator{};
    }
    int end() const { 
    return max;
    }
private:
    const int max;
};

int main() {
    for (const auto i : FibonacciRange{ 50 }) {
    printf("%d ", i); 
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
user@stretch:/tmp$ g++ test.cpp -o test
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:32:46: error: inconsistent begin/end types in range-based ‘for’ statement: ‘FibonacciIterator’ and ‘int’
     for (const auto i : FibonacciRange{ 5000 }) {
                                              ^
test.cpp:32:46: error: conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type ‘FibonacciIterator’ requested
test.cpp:32:46: error: no match for ‘operator!=’ (operand types are ‘FibonacciIterator’ and ‘FibonacciIterator’)
test.cpp:3:10: note: candidate: bool FibonacciIterator::operator!=(int) const
     bool operator!=(int x) const {
          ^~~~~~~~
test.cpp:3:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘FibonacciIterator’ to ‘int’
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `begin` and `end` member functions return different types. Pre-C++17, these types need to be the same, as the error message says

> error: inconsistent begin/end types in range-based ‘for’ statement

From C++17, this restriction on [range-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) loops was relaxed

> As of C++17, the types of the `begin_expr` and the `end_expr` do not have to be the same, and in fact the type of the `end_expr` does not have to be an iterator: it just needs to be able to be compared for inequality with one. This makes it possible to delimit a range by a predicate (e.g. "the iterator points at a null character").

So if you compile your code with the C++17, by passing the `-std=c++17` flag, your code will compile, assuming it satisfies all other constraints, which it does.